# Execute dymola command from command prompt

Tags: command-prompt, modelica, dymola

Is there a way to pass Dymola a command from the Windows command prompt? 
I want to pass it commands like Simulate(), openModel etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could write a script file (.mos) file instead. if are really interested in opening model/simulating a model using a .bat file, then you could also create a .bat file to write a script(.mos) file and then run the script file. I can provide an example for the same.

You could use the following line of code in a batch file and try running the same:

```
SET var=%cd%
cd %var%
echo openModel("%var%\test_case.mo", true) > filename.txt
echo simulateModel("test_case", method="dassl", resultFile="test_case") >> filename.txt
copy "filename.txt" "script.txt"
rename "script.txt" "script.mos"
script.mos
```

I am writing a script file (script.mos) first and then running the same.
please note that I am referring to the current directory.

I am not sure if I have answered your question exactly, please feel free to suggest on the same.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can run the script file via the DOS prompt?

Answer (score 0):

From the Dymola release notes: "A new Java interface for Dymola is available in Dymola 2014 FD01, containing a number of functions to perform operations such as simulating, setting variables, plotting, and exporting data." There is also a old version of this interface, that as far as I know is the only way to drive Dymola from another application. If you want to do it from command prompt I think that the only way is to develop a java application that works as a bridge.

I hope this helps, 
Marco

Comment: Dymola doesn't necessarily need to be driven from the command prompt. I have a situation where the Matlab-dymola interconnection fails after a while (see [matlab-dymola interconnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535958/matlab-dymola-connection-fails-after-a-while)) and I thought I could let Matlab drive the command prompt and so finally drive Dymola.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the interconnection, i.e. close and reopen it, every n steps to avoid the inconvenient? Maybe it is something to do with buffers or mem limits or time limits of the connection and you should end it before one of this constraints occurs.

Comment: As explained in [matlab-dymola interconnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535958/matlab-dymola-connection-fails-after-a-while) I use the dymolaM.m script. The complete code is presented in the link. At the end of the code, you can see a ddeterm command, which I assume is the command to end the interconnectio,.