# ddeexec error with coupling matlab with dymola

Tags: matlab, modelica, dymola

I try to couple matlab with dymola using the function dymolaM from the MFiles developed by Modelon.
The simulation is running without problem, but after x hours of simulation, I get the following message:

```
Error using ddeexec
The first argument 'channel' is not valid.

Error in dymolaM (line 59)
         status = ddeexec(DymolaChannel, deblank(command(i,:)), '', timeout);

Error in MainFile1 (line 218)
    dymolaM(strrep(parChange, ',', ';'));
```

Does anyone have a hint to solve that problem?
Thx!

Comment: Can you provide some more information? What happens after *x* hours (Other than the error)? Currently, this appears to be a very localized problem, because there is no information on the simulation - thus it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535958/matlab-dymola-connection-fails-after-a-while